# Vertical lines in excel proforma, appearing every 12 months on a dynamic basis

Tags: windows, microsoft-excel

I am creating a 90-year proforma for a ground lease residential real estate deal, and I would like to know how to add vertical lines every 12 months in order to better separate the years for when I am presenting the proforma. Since this proforma is dynamic, and dates change when I change input data, I need the vertical lines to appear in the correct spots when I change the date information. I assume this is a conditional formatting rule, but I am not sure how to construct it.

Any clarification on this?

Really appreciate the help.

-Peter

Comment: Can you format based upon what year the dates are within? Using a conditional format based upon the year such as =MOD(YEAR(B2),2)=1 or must it be every 12 months?